# Accented/special characters not recognized by PHP mail form

Tags: php, html, forms, special-characters

As I see, it is an endlessly asked topic... I have read and reread a dozen posts with the same problem and I have not been able to find any solution to solve it in my case: So, for example, "Envío" is displayed as "EnvÃ­o" in the message that I receive.
The code I have is the following... and I have modified it according to many (many!) different suggestions that I have found, without getting any of them to work!

Please, help! =(

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form contact-form">
        <?php
        error_reporting(0);
        $action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
        if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
        { 
        ?>
<form class="php-email-form" id="contact-form" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="etelpmocotua">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="" size="30" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-area" autocomplete="etelpmocotua" /></div>
<div class="form-group mt-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="" size="30" placeholder="e-Mail" class="form-area" autocomplete="etelpmocotua" /></div>
<div class="form-group mt-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" value="" size="30" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-area" autocomplete="etelpmocotua" /></div>
<textarea class="form-control mt-3" name="message" placeholder="Tu mensaje" class="form-area"></textarea>
<div class="my-3"><div class="loading">Enviando...</div></div>
<div class="text-left"><button type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button></div>
</form>

        <?php 
                }  
        else
        {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $phone=$_REQUEST ['phone']; 
        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];

        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($phone=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "<div class='error-message'><strong>Tu mensaje no pudo ser enviado</strong><br>Por favor, completá todos los campos.<br>
        <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\" target=\"_self\"><img src='assets/img/back.png' /></a></div>";
        } 

        else{
        $body .="Nuevo mensaje desde la web!\n
        Nombre: $name
        e-Mail: $email
        Telefono: $phone\n
        Mensaje:\n
        $message";
        $from .="From: 'web@mydomain.com'>\r\n Return-path: $email";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

        $subject .="Contacto WEB";
        mail("web@mydomain.com", $subject, $body, $from);

        echo "<div class='sent-message'>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado<br />
        y pronto será respondido.<br><br>
        <strong>Gracias por contactarnos!<strong></div>"; 
        }
        }
        ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You set the `$headers` variable, containing `charset=UTF-8`, to be used in [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), but you never actually use it there. This code looks sloppy, out of control. Try to format it better and get it under control. For instance, you concatenate a string to the `$headers` variable before you declare it. Switch on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display), so you can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response @KIKOSoftware! I'm definitely lost and just trying to get this old piece of code that I had running on my website in the past.
Could you kindly give me more details about what the problem you are seeing would be?

Comment: Start by switching on error reporting and correct any errors that are reported. Switch error reporting off again when you take the code to production. As for the character problem: Start by adding the UTF-8 header to the `mail()` function. See it that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points which can be fine-tuned, or needed to be corrected

1. You tried specifying utf-8 in your $headers, but your $headers is not used in mail()
2. You are using HTML format, but have tried using `\n` (better use `<br>`)
3. If you have entered carriage return(s) in your message, it will not be displayed properly in HTML , so better use `nl2br` to parse it

So, the revised code will be:
(make sure you have replaced `your_email@your_domain.com` with your `real email address` to receive the mail)

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form contact-form">

<?php

$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 

if ($action=="")  {  ?>

<form class="php-email-form" id="contact-form" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="etelpmocotua">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
<div class="form-group">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="" size="30" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-area" autocomplete="etelpmocotua" /></div>
<div class="form-group mt-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="" size="30" placeholder="e-Mail" class="form-area" autocomplete="etelpmocotua" /></div>
<div class="form-group mt-3"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" value="" size="30" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-area" autocomplete="etelpmocotua" /></div>
<textarea class="form-control mt-3" name="message" placeholder="Tu mensaje" class="form-area"></textarea>
<div class="my-3"><div class="loading">Enviando...</div></div>
<div class="text-left"><button type="submit">Enviar Mensaje</button></div>
</form>

<?php }  else   {
        $name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $phone=$_REQUEST ['phone']; 
        $message=$_REQUEST['message'];

        if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($phone=="")||($message=="")) 
        { 
        echo "<div class='error-message'><strong>Tu mensaje no pudo ser enviado</strong><br>Por favor, completá todos los campos.<br>
        <a href=\"javascript:history.back()\" target=\"_self\"><img src='assets/img/back.png' /></a></div>";
        } else{
        $body .="Nuevo mensaje desde la web!<br><br>
        Nombre: $name<br>
        e-Mail: $email<br>
        Telefono: $phone<br>Mensaje:<br><br>". nl2br($message);
        //    $headers .="From: 'web@mydomain.com'>\r\n Return-path: $email";
        //    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <'. $email . '>' . "\r\n";
        //$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

        $subject .="Contacto WEB";
        mail("your_email@your_domain.com", $subject, $body, $headers);

        echo "<div class='sent-message'>Tu mensaje ha sido enviado<br />
        y pronto será respondido.<br><br>
        <strong>Gracias por contactarnos!<strong></div>"; 
        }
     }
?>

</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Note: `Envío` (e.g name) will still be seen as `Envío` if you use the above code to send out an email

Comment: Thanks @KenLee! Based on your suggestions, I can see that @KIKOSoftware was right... but I couldn't have found a way to make it work without your concrete help. It will be helpful not only for it to work... but for me to better understand the errors... and the extent of my ignorance! hehehe THANK YOU VERY MUCH!